# Display Image when beacon is detected

Tags: swift, xcode, ibeacon, beacon, estimote

I'm trying to make an image appear on the screen of my app, when a beacon is detected. I have currently created a dictionary by assigning an image to each beacon using the minor value, however I'm not sure how to display the image.

```
{   let lookupTable = [12754: "phone-icon", 22279: " StoreLocation"]
```

}

[Here is an image of how I want the image to appear on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLhZQ.jpg)

I need assistance of how to display the image like shown above in the attachment, when a beacon is detected.
Thanks